# Factory data reset not working after root attempt

Tags: factory-reset

I tried to root my HTC rhyme but could not do it properly. I have unlocked bootloader though.

Everything was fine for a long time after that but my mobile has gone very slow now and i wanted to factory reset it. But when i go to factory reset, it stucks on HTC logo and does not turn on. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Look up the Hboot process on YouTube for your model HTC phone. Normally if there's a video then there's links to any files you might need. Follow the directions and thank all the great Devs for making life so easy for us all.